# How to restrict access to web pages with Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

i'd like to restrict access to web page with odoo. Then public can access to /page-1 but only a connected user can access  to /page-2.
It's seems it's not possible by default but do you know is a module provides this fonctionnality ?
Thanks

Comment: When I Google "odoo restrict access" there seems to be a lot of information, is none of it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

you should use auth="user" while you create route method for page-2
Example:

@http.route('/page-2', type='http', auth="user", website=True)
def page_2(self, **kwargs):
    // your code..

Comment: you are right @techsavy but I need to set it dynamically, i cannot create a new method each time I create a new page :(

Comment: @billyJoe  you can use one method for dynamic pages.

@http.route([
        '/shop/page/<int:page>',
   '/shop/category/<model("product.public.category"):category>/page/<int:page>'
    ], type='http', auth="user", website=True)

def shop(self, page=0, category=None, search='', **post):

Comment: @billyJoe  just need to add the security Group on your template view and add the user which you want to access to that particular page.